# Confused on first-child and decendant selector

Tags: html, css

Didn't want to ask, but have gotten very confused on this issue with first-child.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Primary Button |<span> red text here</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Secondary button |<span> yellow text here</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Danger Button |<span> green text here</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the CSS I have is...

```css
 .row span:first-child {
        color: red;
    }
    .row span {
        color: yellow;
    }
    .row span:last-child {
        color: green;
    }
```

```html
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Primary Button |<span> red text here</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Secondary button |<span> yellow text here</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Danger Button |<span> green text here</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Some reason all the text color turns out 'green' because it applies all the color changes, even the red and yellow to it because it thinks that they are the first and last child of the span.  How would I make it so the spans would set the correct text for each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because it thinks that they are the first and last child of the span.

Incorrect.

It is because the `span` is the `:first-child` and `:last-child` of its parent element (which is the `a`).

---

If you want to target the `span` that is a descendant of the `div` that is the `:first-child` of its parent (that is a descendant of the `.row`)… then you have to write a selector that matches the `div`.

```
.row div:first-child span {
```

Comment: so I couldn't reference to element <a> because it's not directly a descendant of the .row div? the only way to reference to <a> is if the <a> wasn't in a div.col-4 and was directly inside the div.row?

I was always under assumption that if you did .row span then it finds all the rows with class 'row' that has a span somewhere inside of it, then puts them into collection.. apparently they have to be direct descendants in order to be considered in the same 'collection'? its not the same as doing like an xpath query?

Comment: "so I couldn't reference to element `<a>`" — You can … but if you care about which div it is a descendant of you have to explicitly mention the div.

Comment: "because it's not directly a descendant of the .row div?" — It is a descendent of the row.

Comment: "I was always under assumption that if you did .row span then it finds all the rows with class 'row' that has a span somewhere inside of it," — No. It finds all the `span`s that have an ancestor of class `row`.

Comment: "apparently they have to be direct descendants" — All descendants are direct descendants. You might be confusing "descendants" and "children". But that's irrelevant to the problem, which is that you care which `div` (first, last, or other in its parent element) the span is descended from).

Comment: Yes, I was confusing descendants and children, however, I now see exactly what I was doing wrong since I was referencing to span:first-child instead of trying to look at the divs. Thanks a ton for your in-depth explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect by targeting the col-4 classes and using the same :first-child / :last-child logic. This will work because the first col-4 is a first-child of the .row div and the last on is the last-child of the .row.

Then the span inside is targeted and colored appropriately.

```css
.col-4:first-child span {
        color: red;
  }

.col-4 span {
    color: yellow;
}

 .col-4:last-child span {
    color: green;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Primary Button |<span> red text here</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Secondary button |<span> yellow text here</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Danger Button |<span> green text here</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```